# i want to use html for a colorpicker jquery plugin for colorpicker to be common

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, raphael

i want to use html common for colorpicker in a jquery plugin...having raphael colorpicker 
[raphaeljs.com/picker.html](http://raphaeljs.com/picker.html)
...
every time i instantiate it on multiple selectors i get multiple colorwheels and colorpickers..

i used

```
var cw = $('#col_wheel_holder').colorwheel(170,'#112112');
```

like..in 
plugin code

```
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        var cw = $('#col_wheel_holder').colorwheel(170,'#112112');
        var cpkr = $('#col_picker_holder').colorpicker(170, "#331");
        var $colpikr_container = $('#color_pikr');
        return this.each(function ( i, el ) {
            var colpik = Object.create(Cpk);
            colpik.init(options,this,cw,cpkr,$colpikr_container);
            $.data(this,'cpkr',colpik);

        });
};

$('#el1,#el2').cpkr();
```

Answer (score 0):

JQ handles the .each iteration. Just write as if you're dropping into one element. When $ sees that there's more than one element it will hit each one with your function. Lose the .each